# mathbb generates strange characters for numbers and greek letters

Tags: amssymb

I'm simply compiling this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}             % AMS Math

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eee}
\mathbb{R} \mathbb{A}  \mathbb{1}  \mathbb{\Omega} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is really strange. What is going on with amssymb package?

[image]

Comment: Don't use \mathbb for numbers and greek. It is a command only for letters.

Comment: then how people usually type this $\mathbb{1}$. I've seen may times in the literature

Comment: Check the symbol list http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive (Table 299: Math Alphabets).

Comment: Thanks for referencing the table. using "amssymb" I can generate nice blackboard bold letters such as $\mathbb{R}$. But this package produces strange characters for greek letters, as mentioned in my post above. However, if I use "mathbbol", instead of amssymb, it does generate blackboard bold greek letters. But the problem is the letters such as $\mathbb{R}$ are not as nice as before.

Comment: you can declare both alphabets and use ams for letters and a different one for digits.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- please answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton done

Answer (score 6):

You can declare both fonts, I called them `\amsmathbb` and `\mathbb` here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amssymb}             % AMS Math

\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\amsmathbb}{AMSb}%

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eee}
\amsmathbb{R} \amsmathbb{A}  \mathbb{1}  \mathbb{\Omega} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not working, I compiled your code exactly and the 1 and  Ω came out as normal fonts.

Comment: @YanKingYin it should work or you get an error about fonts not being installed, if you can't get it working ask a new question and show your log file from the above test file.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use the following format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}
    \item $\mathbb{1}_X$
    \item $\mathbb{\Omega}$
    \item $\mathbb{\Delta}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Blackboard Characters]

Comment: why do u recom?