# problems with $\mathbb{1}$ in pandoc

Tags: pandoc, mathbb

I use pandoc, `pandoc in.tex --latex-engine=xelatex -o out.pdf`, and want characters like "ℝ" to be produced from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\let\mathbb\undefined  % delete the command definition
\usepackage{bbold}     % let bbold define its own \mathbb command
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{123R}$
\end{document}
```

I get "⊮⊭⊯ℝ" in my pdf. It produces correct output in html and docx.

```
pandoc 1.19.2.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.9, skylighting 0.1.1.4
```

I am sure the problem is having the right font for pdf, in my case. 
So the right question may be - which font should I use for blackboard bold numbers for pdf for pandoc. Keeping in mind that `pdflatex` has the fonts somehow.

Comment: You need another font, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291329/mathbb-generates-strange-characters-for-numbers-and-greek-letters

Comment: @Ulrike, I tried, but even the example from that answer does not produce anything reasonable when I run it via pandoc:
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    l.61 \amsmathbb

Comment: What does `pdffonts` command say for the pandoc version, and what does it say for the pdflatex version?

Comment: By the way, does pandoc produce TeX log?  Can you post it?

Comment: @Boris, thank you; so far I'm clueless how do I run `pdffonts` command. I did produce a log, using pandoc's --verbose; it's about 16k. It also refers a log file, but by the time it finishes, the file is gone.

Comment: Can you put it somewhere and post a link?  Or just send me it through e-mail.

Comment: Boris, I think we are past it. The problem was with bad pandoc template anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With a little help from my friends, found a solution.
First, change the pandoc template. E.g. can use this one: https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template

Will have to create the folder for templates, and then
`cp ~/Downloads/eisvogel.latex ~/.pandoc/templates/`

It will work with the following command:
`pandoc in.tex --latex-engine=xelatex --template eisvogel -o out.pdf`